# What do we call this line in video editing?

Tags: video-editing, editing, timestamp

This might be an obvious question but I can't seem to find the answer to it.
What do we call the line highlighted in yellow?

[image: the line that is highlighted in yellow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The band you are seeing is usually called the video timeline,
which is the area of a video editing application where you arrange
your video clips and map out all the edits you'd like to apply and where.

The name of the line marking the current position depends on the
application that's displaying the video/audio.
It may be called "Playhead" or "Cursor" or even just "Current position".
There is not one term that is universally accepted.

Comment: Insertion point, cue, tracking, ... video editing is not alone here, there has been many names used over the years... (yes I have many years of computer use).